# Build a tree of outputs with numbered vertices and edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-state-machine

I am trying to understand this task that is related to Deterministic functions, Moore diagrams, and canonical equations which requires several requirements.

We have this equation
$y(k) = \{x(1), x(2) → x(1), x(2) ⊕ x(3), x(4), x(5), ...\}$

we have to

1. Build a tree of outputs with numbered vertices and edges
2. Find the weight of the tree, build a truncated tree
3. Build a Moore diagram
4. Build a canonical table and derive canonical equations

I have no idea about how we can build a tree from the equation also what does $\to$ mean in the equation, if you can give me any resources to understand I would be glad

how can we Build a tree of outputs with numbered vertices and edges?

How can we find the weight of the tree, and build a truncated tree?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how can we Build a tree of outputs with numbered vertices and edges?

how can we Find the weight of the tree, and build a truncated tree?